# UISlider with array of numbers

Tags: arrays, swift, uislider

I have an array of numbers and would like to let the user choose which number by using the UISlider. However with my current code whenever I simulate the app and try to move the UISlider the app crashes and says "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" within the IBAction func reactionVolumeSlider. I only have 3 numbers to choose from within the array 10, 20, and 50.

```
      import UIKit

class SelectAttributesViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var kitPickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var reactionVolumeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfSampleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var volumeOfTemplateDNATextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!


    let kits = ["Kit 1", "Kit 2"]
    let pcrReactionVolumeArray = [10,20,50]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.numberOfSampleTextField.delegate = self
        self.volumeOfTemplateDNATextField.delegate = self
        kitPickerView.dataSource = self
        kitPickerView.delegate = self

        //slider.addTarget(self, action: "reactionVolumeSlider", for: .valueChanged)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func reactionVolumeSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let currentValue = pcrReactionVolumeArray[Int(sender.value)]
        reactionVolumeLabel.text = "\(currentValue) μL"

    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
       return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return kits.count

    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if row == 0{ print(kits[row])

        }else if row == 1{
           createAlert(title: "Kit not available", message: "More kits will be added soon!")
        }

    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return kits[row]
    }
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
           guard let oldText = textField.text, let r = Range(range, in: oldText) else {
               return true
           }

           let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: r, with: string)
           let isNumeric = newText.isEmpty || (Double(newText) != nil)
           let numberOfDots = newText.components(separatedBy: ".").count - 1

           let numberOfDecimalDigits: Int
           if let dotIndex = newText.firstIndex(of: ".") {
               numberOfDecimalDigits = newText.distance(from: dotIndex, to: newText.endIndex) - 1
           } else {
               numberOfDecimalDigits = 0
           }

           return isNumeric && numberOfDots <= 1 && numberOfDecimalDigits <= 2
       }
    func createAlert (title: String, message: String){
           let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
           alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (Action) in
               alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
           }))
           self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }





}
```

Comment: Print `Int(sender.value)` in `reactionVolumeSlider` before using it and let us know what it says.

Comment: It prints out the number 10.

Comment: @Hunter - That's your problem. It's trying to display the 10th element in your array that only has three elements.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on the following line:

`let currentValue = pcrReactionVolumeArray[Int(sender.value)]`

Your senders value **is** the "currentValue" that you want.

Just use `let currentValue = Int(sender.value)`, there is no reason to index into your array here

Comment: He only wants the current value to be 10, 20, or 50.  That's not what the sender value would provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 entries in your array, and you want to use a slider value to index into the array, you want your slider to return a value from 0 (first element of your array) to 2 (last element of your array).

Remember: your slider returns an index, not a value.

More generally, for an array with n elements, you want your slider to range from 0 to n-1.

Comment: Thank you. What type of UI element would you recommend for a user to enter these 3 numbers other than a textfield and pickerview?

Comment: @Hunter Your UISlider should work fine if you set its maximum value to 2 (and minimum to 0).

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying. If my answer solved your problem, you should accept it.